# TransactionSearch paypal API deprecated

Tags: api, paypal, transactions

We need to had the transactions made by our users.
We want to call paypal API, do a login and get a transactions with our merchant_id as criteria.
We use paypalrestsdk for python.
Seems that TransactionSearch method is deprecated, how can we implement that?
Is there a new method for this or we must implements ourself the code?
Thanks a lot.
Angela

Answer (score 0):

[TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) is not fully deprecated.  It will still function now and for many years.  Too many people are still using the Classic APIs for them to completely remove it.  If you already have that setup and working you'll be fine running with it.

That said, they are trying to get people into the REST APIs as much as possible.  For that, you would use [PayPal Sync](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/).

If you happen to be working with PHP, take a look at our [class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It will make either option very easy for you to integrate.